# Delphi -> obtain record type from untyped parameter

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I am using Delphi XE2.
As a workaround to Delphi not supporting forward references to Record types I started using untyped parameters.

How can I obtain the Type of an untyped Parameter?

```
procedure TSomeRecord.TransformBy(const AUntypedParam);
begin
// how can I ensure that **AUntypedParam** is of a specific record type?
```

I need to make sure that AUntypedParam is of a specific type, otherwise an exception should be thrown.
Thank you!

Comment: Add a signature into your records.

Comment: BTW, it should be possible to circumvent the inability to declare forward record references by using record helpers.

Comment: Yes, record helpers are the way I get around this issue.

Comment: Yes, indeed record helpers do work, but there are two drawbacks:
1) You need to reference another Unit (with the helper methods)
2) XE2 Intellisense does not pickup helper methods. According to David's answer on another question this seems to be tackled in XE5.
At the end I think I will stick with helper methods as well.

Comment: You can have the helper declarations in the same unit.

Comment: @santiagoIT You do not need to reference another unit. You can declare the helper in the same unit as the record. Personally I'd rather do without the Intellisense and have the compiler check that I'm not passing nonsense to the method!

Comment: @DavidHeffernan If you declare the helper in the same Unit as the record how do you overcome the circular reference problem? That is actually the problem I am trying to workaround. Can the helper be defined entirely within the implementation section?

Comment: You just put the helper after the declaration of the two records that are mutually interdependent. You typically don't want the helper declared in the implementation section because it's rather useless there. It can only be of use to code in that implementation section.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan if you ever get a chance it would be great if you could put something very basic into pastebin.com (or any other similar tool) that shows how you structure your code to deal with interdependent records. We normally try to keep one type per Unit, but it seems that you define multiple types in the same unit. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: I do define multiple types in the same unit. But even if you define types in separate units, then you can still use helpers to break dependency. Just put the helper in the same unit as the type it is helping. After the declaration of that type.

Comment: Anyway, here's a pastebin of my main workhouse records: http://pastebin.com/dZSsysPH They are a 3-vector and a 3x3 matrix. We use them for geometry in our structural FE code. And I want them to be interdependent. The helper is declared last. If you split these into separate units you would have TVector in one, and TMatrix and the helper in the other. The second unit (that containing TMatrix and the helper) would use the first.

Comment: This thread in the EMB forum was enlightening: [`Concrete scenario where record helpers are the only viable solution`](https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?messageID=541662&#).

Comment: @LURD If you filter out the input from the Church of Veltology.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, yes, that part goes into the amusement account.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan thanks so much for the pastebin. It is now very clear how you organize your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I ensure that `AUntypedParam` is of a specific record type?

You cannot. That's pretty much the modus operandi of untyped parameters. When you say to the compiler, don't check the type of the actual parameter, the compiler takes you at your word and lets you pass anything that you like. You cannot have it both ways.

---

@LURD astutely points out that you can use record helpers to work around this compiler limitation. I do hope that somebody from Embarcadero reads questions on Stack Overflow. This must be the third or fourth time in the past week that we've had a question due to the limitations of extended records.